# What's the expected behavior for MySQL load data infile for auto increment field?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a production MySQL database, for some reason, I need to load some data into it from our development database which has similar schema. The data is output through mysql -e "select * from :>somefile method.

The schema for the target table has an ID which is auto_increment and is the primary key.  What's the likely behavior for the ID filed?

Case 1. No same ID in both dbs, will it be loaded directly without any impact? And any future insertion start with the largest ID?

Case 2, With same ID in the two dbs, will this generate an error?

Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on what you have and what you need.